# how to write the variable of width and height in scss. so i can importe them into the html div

Tags: sass

```css
constant.scss

$widthsize:(500);
$heightsize:(300);
----------------------------------------------------------
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html  >
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,  maximum-scale=1">
        <title>Spider Leads</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"></link><!-- comment -->
    </head>
    <body class="bodybg">
        <div>
            <img src="images/logo.bmp" alt="Spider leads" height="$heightsize" width=$widthsize>
        </div>
        </body>
         

</html>
```

$heightsize:  how to write  a 100px value  in here ?
$widthsize: how to write  a 100px value in here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this. An SCSS file needs to be compiled to a CSS file first, but these variables in the SCSS file also have to be used somewhere in the SCSS file. If you just set some variables in the SCSS file but don't use them, it won't work (i.e., the compiled CSS file will be empty). Do it like this:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/802112/pexels-photo-802112.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Spider leads">
</body>
</html>
```

**styles.scss**

```
$widthsize: 100px;
$heightsize: 100px;

img {
    width: $widthsize;
    height: $heightsize;
}
```

**styles.css**

*The CSS file is generated automatically when you compile the SCSS file.*

```
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=styles.css.map */
```

Comment: thanks you  bro , i was just trying something will not ever work , using variable inside html  .  so the concusion thats we cannt use a variable inside html right ?

Comment: You're welcome. :) Correct, SCSS doesn't work this way.

Comment: Upvote recorded,  answer accepted